# The best way to capture user input int with error handling loop

Tags: c++, user-input, iostream

In my case, I have to make sure the user input is either 1 or 2, or 3.

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void invalid_choice_prompt() {
    string msg = "\nInvalid Command! Please try again.";
    cout << msg << endl;
}

int ask_user_rps_check_input(int user_choice) {
    if (user_choice == 1 || user_choice == 2 || user_choice == 3) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int ask_user_rps() {
    // ask user's choice of Rock or Paper or Scissors
    while (1) {
        string msg =
            "\nPlease enter your choice:\nRock - 1\nPaper - 2\nScissors - 3";
        cout << msg << endl;

        int user_choice;
        cin >> user_choice;

        if (ask_user_rps_check_input(user_choice)) {
            return user_choice;
        }
        invalid_choice_prompt();
    }
}

int main() {
    ask_user_rps();

    return 0;
}
```

The code is capable to handle the situation when the input is an integer, but when the input are characters or strings, the program will be trapped in the infinite loop.

Is there any elegant way to do this? I've found some methods about using `cin.ignore` to ignore the specified length of io buffer, but I don't think this method is flexible enough. I am looking for a more flexible solution.

Comment: First of all, read full lines. Then attempt to parse the contents of that line into what you want. [`std::stoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) might be helpful there. I also recommend you put the input handling and validation into its own separate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from a stream using operator `>>` takes as many characters from the stream as the target type accepts; the rest will remain in the stream for subsequent reads. If the input has a format error (e.g. a leading alphabetical characters when an integer is expected), then an error-flag is set, too. This error-flag can be checked with `cin.fail()`. It remains set until it gets explicitly cleared. So if your code is...

```
int user_choice;
cin >> user_choice;
```

and if you then enter something that is not a number, e.g. `asdf`, then `user_choice` has an undefined value, an error-flag `cin.fail()` is (and reamins) set. So any subsequent read will fail, too.

To overcome this, you have to do three things:

First, check the error-flag. You can do this either through calling `cin.fail()` after a read attempt of through checking the return value of the expression `(cin >> user_choice)`, which is the same as calling `cin.fail()`.

Second, in case of an error, you need to clear the error-flag using `cin.clear()`. Otherwise, any attempt to read in anything afterwards will fail.

Third, if you want to continue with reading integral values, you need to take the invalid characters from the stream. Otherwise, you will read in `asdf` into a variable of type integer again and again, and it will fail again and again. You can use `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');` to take all characters until EOF or an end-of-line from the input buffer.
The complete code for reading an integral value with error-handling could look as follows:

```
int readNumber() {

    int result;
    
    while (!(cin >> result)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        cout << "Input is not a number." << std::endl;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for the explanation of ```cin``` buffer, and this method is also graceful.

Answer (score 2):

I think an option would be to collect the user input to a string and then move it to stringstream using getline kind of like this:

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
//Now check if the input is correct. if it is, then:
std::stringstream stream;
stream << input;
int num;
stream >> num;
```

I'm not sure if this is a good method but it works.

Comment: This is a very elegant method, at least I know so far. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest solution would be to check the cin stream failure something like below:

```
int ask_user_rps() {
// ask user's choice of Rock or Paper or Scissors
while (1) {
    string msg =
        "\nPlease enter your choice:\nRock - 1\nPaper - 2\nScissors - 3";
    cout << msg << endl;

    int user_choice;
    cin >> user_choice;
    
    if(cin.fail()) {
        invalid_choice_prompt();
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(256,'\n');
        continue;
    }

    if (ask_user_rps_check_input(user_choice)) {
        return user_choice;
    }
    invalid_choice_prompt();
}
}
```

Comment: this method it specified the size of 256 buffer to be ignored, it is what I pursue.

Answer (score 0):

Take input as char

```
string user_choice;
cin >> user_choice;
```

check input  is valid or not `if(user_choice=='1')`

Comment: Which could lead to trouble if the user inputs more than a single digit, as the remaining will still be in the input buffer.

Comment: yes, but if we use string then it will not.